# How to view user passwords as plain text in Wordpress's database?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, hash, jmeter, profiling

**What I'm trying to do:**

I have a dummy Wordpress site that I'm using to profile various aspects of my architecture. I've generated 100 dummy users with the intention of using them as a workload in Jmeter. However, Wordpress hashes the password of each user. Is it possible for me to change the settings to view the passwords as plain text?

**What I have done:**

I've exported the user info into an csv file. I was planning on using this file for Jmeter to read data from for my test plan. As mentioned before, the passwords are hashed, preventing Jmeter from being able to login with each user credentials properly.

Comment: I sincerely hope that WordPress *doesn't have* an option to store user passwords in plain text.  Do you not specify a password when creating a user?  Or can you not update the passwords for the 100 dummy users to known values?

Comment: The login info for the users are generated randomly using the app FakerPress. I could go through the process of creating each profile individually and write down their info, but that would be a painstaking effort.

Comment: You can [update a user's password programatically](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/9919).  Whether you want to set all 100 to the same password or to 100 different passwords is really up to you and the needs of what you're building.  Either way, that data (username/password combinations) will need to be in your tests so you'll need to keep track of it anyway.  Unless you can somehow find an option in WordPress to store passwords in plain text (which it really **really** shouldn't have, and if it does nobody should ever be tempted to turn it on).

Comment: Thank you, I think this is my best option. I agree, having that information in plain text is a bad idea. I imagine I'm the minority in needing this information presented in such a fashion though.